# How to call a method of a class embedding List<X> and List<Y>, and of Y, from the X elements themselves?

Tags: c#, list, collections, associations, owner

I though I would easily find an answer to this question but I couldn't find yet.

Let's say I have the following classes :

```
public class Universe
{
    public list<Human> Humans { get; set; }
    public list<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public God AlphaOmega { get; set; }
    
    public void UniverseAction()
    { 
        //dosmthg
    }

    public Animal FindAnAnimal()
    {
        //find an animal
    }
}

public class Animal
{
     //many Animal things
    public void AnimalyStuff()
    {
        //DoSmthg
    }
}

public class God
{
    public bool CantTouchThis = true;
}


public class Human
{
    //many Human things
    public void CallingUniverseAction()
    {
        //How to?
    }

    public void CallingAnimalyStuff()
    {
                  
    }
}
```

Note that those names are purely given as examples, I could have used A, B, C & D.

So I want that all humans be able to call `UniverseAction()` so from a specific `Human` I can use it.
I also want that humans be able to call `AnimalyStuff()` so a specific `Human` would need to access the `FindAnAnimal` in `Universe` to retrieve a specific `Animal` and do the `AnimalyStuff()`

For a while when dealing with this kind of requirement I used to pass `Universe` in the constructor of `Human`. Though I don't want that Human can expose all method / parameters of Universe. For instance, `Human` should not interract with `AlphaOmega`

What would be the most appropriate way to do it?
Is it through an `action delegate` that I'll pass in the constructor? If so how, I never used action delegates. Also will I not end up with passing many delegates if I want Human to access many methods?

Comment: Does your code compile? Those two unnamed properties at the start of your `Universe` confuse me

Comment: aha sorry, my code is dummy code, but yeah i forgot to name them. Done

Comment: Read up on classic object-oriented design.  Figure out what your nouns (classes) are, and what your verbs (methods on those classes) are.  Then read up on _dependency injection_.  That's a way to reduce the _coupling_ between your classes.  Also read up on _separation of concerns_.  As you describe it, everything is coupled together and it's very hard to follow.  Once you write a system based on your spec and let it get maintained for a year or two, the code will likely be undecipherable.

Comment: You need to add a field member on elements which thus know the collection where are located. This is called the owner pattern. I'm not sure if there is a standard design pattern for this and its name. For example: `public class Animal { List<Animal> /*or Universe here in fact*/ Owner; }` and when an item is added to the list, the owner is set. It requires a custom list and manages everything to be consistent and robust (a custom List is better, but not mandatory). Thus adapt Universe here. See @DekuDesu's answer: I took a quick look and it's fine. For CallingAnimalyStuff what the hell is that?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options available to you if you want to limit the available information to `Human`.

- If you are okay with only *hiding* the information, where it is still there, but not accessible unless you explicitly un-hide it consider using a *Interface* to limit the available members.
- If you are okay with the `Universe` being passed around, but certain members being inaccessible to `Human`, consider using the `protected` modifier to limit access to members that inherit from the `Universe` class.
- If you are okay with passing things in the constructor(like you recommended) you could pass any number of methods(delegates) to the human class so they can get the information any time they need, but it involves more complex implementation(I already did most of the work for you below)
- If you're not sure what you want to do, and this doesn't **need**(for some specific business requirement) to work in the way you have described - Consider researching general [Object Oriented Programing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) design patterns. There's a ton of resources online that can teach you OOP. The main topic I would recommend is the *SOLID principles* which will teach you a lot and be really useful. *Thanks [@flydog57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4739488/flydog57)  for mentioning this, as this would be more useful in the long run.*

**Interfaces**
To visually hide/abstract the information unless explicitly accessed(casted) you can implement an `IUniverse` interface that defines only the members that you want publicly accessible.

```cs
// these would be the only accessible members
public interface IUniverse
{
    Animal FindAnAnimal();
    void UniverseAction();
}

public class Universe : IUniverse { ... }

public class Human
{
    private readonly IUniverse universe;
    public Human(IUniverse universe)
    {
        this.universe = universe;
    }
}
```

Using interfaces to abstract which information should be available where can be really powerful! However, this does not prevent `Human` from casting the `IUniverse` to a `Universe` object explicitly and access it's other public members.

**Protected Modifier**
You can use the `protected` modifier (and a couple other ones) to completely remove access to information to other classes that don't meet certain requirements. For example the `protected` modifier would prohibit access to any `protected` members from any class that does **not** inherit from `Universe`. Make sure to checkout [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for more information about the other options available to you.

```cs
public class Universe
{
    protected List<Human> Humans { get; set; } = new();
    protected List<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new();
    protected God AlphaOmega { get; set; }

    public void UniverseAction()
    {
        //dosmthg
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(UniverseAction));
    }

    public Animal FindAnAnimal()
    {
        //find an animal
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(FindAnAnimal));
        return Animals.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public class Human
{
    private readonly Universe universe;
    public Human(Universe universe)
    {
        this.universe = universe;
    }
    
    //many Human things
    public void CallingUniverseAction()
    {
        //How to?
        universe.UniverseAction(); // works
        UniverseAction.Humans.Clear(); // no access it's protected
    }

    public void CallingAnimalyStuff()
    {
        var animal = universe.FindAnAnimal(); // works
        UniverseAction.Animals.Clear(); // no access it's protected
        AlphaOmega.Kill(); // no access it's protected
    }
}
```

**Passing Delegates**
You could for example pass delegates to the human to avoid passing around the `Universe` instance it self. Any method group is *usually*  convertible to some form of [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0) or [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0). Make sure to checkout [Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0) and [Funcs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) for more information on both and how they can be passed around.

You can pass these around super simply for example:

```cs
public class Universe
{
    public Human CreateHuman()
    {
        var newHuman = new Human(UniverseAction, FindAnAnimal);

        Humans.Add(newHuman);

        return newHuman;
    }    
}

public class Human
{
    private readonly Action universeAction;
    private readonly Func<Animal> animalyStuff;

    public Human(Action universeAction, Func<Animal> animalyStuff)
    {
        this.universeAction= universeAction;
        this.animalyStuff = animalyStuff;
    }
    
    //many Human things
    public void CallingUniverseAction()
    {
        //How to?
        universeAction?.Invoke();
    }

    public void CallingAnimalyStuff()
    {
        var animal = animalyStuff?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

You could also implement a more robust, but more complex system if you need to pass a large amount of functions in the constructor like 20+. Passing a large number of things in a constructor is **not** a viable pattern, but it could work if you really wanted to, if you are **required** to do it to interop with legacy systems.

Here's a short snippet of what an implementation of that using reflection might look like.

```cs
public class Universe
{
    protected List<Human> Humans { get; set; } = new();
    protected List<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new();
    protected God AlphaOmega { get; set; }

    public Human CreateHuman()
    {
        var newHuman = new Human(
            (nameof(FindAnAnimal), (Func<Animal>)FindAnAnimal),
            (nameof(UniverseAction), (Action)UniverseAction)
        );

        Humans.Add(newHuman);

        return newHuman;
    }

    public void UniverseAction()
    {
        //dosmthg
    }

    public Animal FindAnAnimal()
    {
        //find an animal
    }
}

public class Human
{
    //many Human things
    public void CallingUniverseAction()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(Universe.UniverseAction));
    }

    public void CallingAnimalyStuff()
    {
        var animal = Invoke(nameof(Universe.FindAnAnimal));
    }

    public Human(params (string Name, object Delegate)[] Methods)
    {
        foreach (var item in Methods)
        {
            InvokableReferences.Add(item.Name, item.Delegate);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> InvokableReferences = new();

    public object Invoke(string DelegateName, params object[] Parameters)
    {
        if (InvokableReferences.ContainsKey(DelegateName))
        {
            object storedDelegate = InvokableReferences[DelegateName];

            var delegateType = storedDelegate.GetType();

            // check for the invoke method
            var invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod(nameof(Invoke));

            if (invokeMethod != null)
            {
                // check to see if it's an action or a func
                var methodParams = invokeMethod.GetParameters();

                if (methodParams is null)
                {
                    // since there were no parameters then it is probably an Action or Func<T>
                    return invokeMethod.Invoke(storedDelegate, null);
                }

                // if it requires parameters it's probably a Action<T,..N> or Func<T...N,TResult>
                // make sure we have enough parameters to invoke the method
                if (methodParams.Length == Parameters.Length)
                {
                    return invokeMethod.Invoke(storedDelegate, Parameters);
                }
            }
        }

        // if we failed to find the item return null;
        return default;
    }
}
```